# Jquery datatable reload with local data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using [datatable](http://datatables.net/) plugin as grid to populate data. i have maintain local object array to temperately add data

```
var tableSetup = [];
```

i can bind the data to datatable like this

```
var datatableTabletools = undefined;
var tableSetupGrid = $('#facility-setup').DataTable({
    searching: false,
    ordering: false,
    scrollY: "300px",
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging: false,
    info: false,
    preDrawCallback: () => {
        if (!datatableTabletools) {
            datatableTabletools = new ResponsiveDatatablesHelper($('#facility-setup'), datatableTabletools);
        }
    },
    rowCallback: (nRow) => { datatableTabletools.createExpandIcon(nRow); },
    drawCallback: (oSettings) => { datatableTabletools.respond(); },
    data: tableSetup,

    columns: [
        { data: "nooftables" },
        { data: "noofchairspertable" },
        { data: "noofblocks" },
        { data: "noofrows" },
        { data: "noofcolumns" },
        { data: "color" },
        { data: null }
    ],
    columnDefs: [
        {
            targets: 6,
            render: (data, type, row) => {
                var btnschedule = ' <button class=\'btn btn-xs btn-default\' data-toggle=\'modal\'  data-button-id="0"><i class=\'fa fa-calendar\'></i> Schedule</button>';
                var btnEdit = ' <button class=\'btn btn-xs btn-default\' data-toggle=\'modal\'  data-button-id="1" data-original-title=\'Edit Row\'><i class=\'fa fa-pencil\'></i> Edit</button>';
                return btnEdit + ' ' + btnschedule;
            }
        }
    ]

});
```

problem is when i add data to array datatable not reload with newly added data 
i tried with below code

```
tableSetupGrid.row.add({ nooftables: 1, noofchairspertable: 2, noofblocks: 3, noofrows: 4, noofcolumns: 5, color: 6 });
tableSetupGrid.rows().invalidate().draw()
```

what was the problem with my code

regards

Comment: `tableSetupGrid.row.add({ nooftables: 1, noofchairspertable: 2, noofblocks: 3, noofrows: 4, noofcolumns: 5, color: 6 }).draw()` is the normal way to do it - any errors in the console?

Comment: No there's no error on console